# Handling exceptions in Kafka streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Had gone through multiple posts but most of them are related handling Bad messages not about exception handling while processing them.

I want to know to how to handle the messages that is been received by the stream application and there is an exception while processing the message? The exception could be because of multiple reasons like Network failure, RuntimeException etc.,

- Could someone suggest what is the right way to do? Should I use
  `setUncaughtExceptionHandler`? or is there a better way?
- How to handle retries?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

it depends what do you want to do with exceptions on producer side.
if exception will be thrown on producer (e.g. due to Network failure or kafka broker has died), stream will die by default. and with kafka-streams version 1.1.0 you could override default behavior by implementing `ProductionExceptionHandler` like the following:

```
public class CustomProductionExceptionHandler implements ProductionExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public ProductionExceptionHandlerResponse handle(final ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record,
                                                     final Exception exception) {
        log.error("Kafka message marked as processed although it failed. Message: [{}], destination topic: [{}]",  new String(record.value()), record.topic(), exception);
        return ProductionExceptionHandlerResponse.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final Map<String, ?> configs) {
    }

}
```

from handle method you could return either `CONTINUE` if you don't want streams dying on exception, on return `FAIL` in case you want stream stops (FAIL is default one).
and you need specify this class in stream config:

```
default.production.exception.handler=com.example.CustomProductionExceptionHandler
```

Also pay attention that `ProductionExceptionHandler` handles only exceptions on producer, and it will not handle exceptions during processing message with stream methods `mapValues(..)`, `filter(..)`, `branch(..)` etc, you need to wrap these method logic with try / catch blocks (put all your method logic into try block to guarantee that you will handle all exceptional cases):

```
.filter((key, value) -> { try {..} catch (Exception e) {..} })
```

as I know, we don't need to handle exceptions on consumer side explicitly, as kafka streams will retry automatically consuming later (as offset will not be changed until messages will be consumed and processed); e.g. if kafka broker will be not reachable for some time, you will got exceptions from kafka streams, and when broken will be up, kafka stream will consume all messages. so in this case we will have just delay and nothing corrupted/lost.

with `setUncaughtExceptionHandler` you will not be able to change default behavior like with `ProductionExceptionHandler`, with it you could only log error or send message into failure topic.

---

**Update since `kafka-streams` `2.8.0`**

since `kafka-streams` `2.8.0`, you have the ability to automatically replace failed stream thread (that caused by uncaught exception)
using `KafkaStreams` method `void setUncaughtExceptionHandler(StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler eh);` with `StreamThreadExceptionResponse.REPLACE_THREAD`. For more details please take a look at [Kafka Streams Specific Uncaught Exception Handler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-671%3A+Introduce+Kafka+Streams+Specific+Uncaught+Exception+Handler)

```
kafkaStreams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(ex -> {
    log.error("Kafka-Streams uncaught exception occurred. Stream will be replaced with new thread", ex);
    return StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler.StreamThreadExceptionResponse.REPLACE_THREAD;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Vasiliy for the input. This may be basic question. How does throwing an exception in Producer will cause the stream to die?

Comment: if exception occurred either during processing message (like during your logic in `.mapValues(..)`, `.filter(..)`), or during producing message to destination (sink) topic (like by Network issue), your stream will die. you could test it by throwing any exception during processor. all uncaught exceptions will cause kafka stream die

Comment: Sure. Will try that.

Comment: Just want to add, that setting an uncaught exception handler is only to inform you that a thread dies -- the callback happens after the fact. As @VasiliySarzhynskyi pointed out, it depends on what you want to do if an exception occurs.

Comment: if exception occurred either during processing message (like during your logic in .mapValues(..), .filter(..)), ... > ok so you have to raise runtime exception to stop the stream, because if it is just an Exception, you  will have to try/catch and return something ?

Comment: @Marcelkobain it depends on your business requirements. if it's critical for you not to lose the message, in that case, you could catch exception, fire your alert (so you will be aware of the issue), and rethrow exception, and in this case, stream will be stopped. for other cases, it might be normal to skip failed messages, so in that case you catch exception and does not rethrow it

Answer (score 6):

For handling exceptions on the consumer side,

1) You can add a default exception handler in producer with the following property.

```
"default.deserialization.exception.handler" = "org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler";
```

Basically apache provides three exception handler classes as

1) LogAndContiuneExceptionHandler which you can take as

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
           LogAndContinueExceptionHandler.class);
```

2) LogAndFailExceptionHandler

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
           LogAndFailExceptionHandler.class);
```

3) LogAndSkipOnInvalidTimestamp

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
           LogAndSkipOnInvalidTimestamp.class);
```

For custom exception handling,

1)you can implement the DeserializationExceptionHandler interface and override the handle() method.

2) Or you can extend the above-mentioned classes.

Comment: can you point me to an example for a working custom deserialization exception handler code ?

Answer (score 2):

**setUncaughtExceptionHandler** doesn't help to handle exception, it works after the stream has terminated due to some exception which was not caught.

Kafka provides few ways to handle exceptions. A simple *try-catch{}* would help catch exceptions in the processor code but kafka deserialization exception (can be due to data issues) and production exception(occurs during communication with broker) requires **DeserializationExceptionHandler**  and  **ProductionExceptionHandler** respectively. By default a kafka application would fail if it encounter any of these.

You can find on this [post](https://thevoidcoder.dev/posts/2020-08-30-handling-failures-in-kafka-stream/)

Answer (score 0):

In Spring cloud stream you confgure your custom deserialization handler using following:

- **spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.deserialization.exception.handler**=your-package-name.CustomLogAndContinueExceptionHandler
- CustomLogAndContinueExceptionHandler **extends LogAndContinueExceptionHandler or implements DeserializationExceptionHandler**
- CustomLogAndContinueExceptionHandler **DeserializationHandlerResponse.CONTINUE or FAIL** depending on your usecase

```
@Slf4j
public class CustomLogAndContinueExceptionHandler extends LogAndContinueExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public DeserializationHandlerResponse handle(ProcessorContext context, ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record,
            Exception exception) {
.... some business logic here ....
        log.error("Message failed: taskId: {}, topic: {}, partition: {}, offset: {}, , detailerror : {}",
                context.taskId(), record.topic(), record.partition(), record.offset(), exception.getMessage());
        return DeserializationHandlerResponse.CONTINUE;
    }
}
```