# How to handle the processing exceptions in Kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

[Handling exceptions in Kafka streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299528/handling-exceptions-in-kafka-streams) is similar question but the accepted answer only talks about the productionException. How to handle the exceptions occurring during the processing  and thereby how to control the manually offset committing.

Comment: Maybe you can find out what you are after in this doc: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Architecture#:~:text=For%20fatal%20exceptions%2C%20Kafka%20Streams,up%20with%20an%20fatal%20exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle them manually, ie, use own `try-catch` blocks and react to them accordingly.

Comment: how can I perform manual offset commit Acknowledge#acknowledge() or Acknowledge#nack() with `try-catch`?

Comment: Not sure what your question is? But in Kafka Streams, you cannot control committing but it's done for you automatically. If you question is about, for example, how can you handle an error in `filter()`, you could for example just `return false` if an exceptions occurs to drop the record. -- It's highly business logic dependent how you want to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the usage of this library helpful [Libraries for error handling in Kafka Streams](https://github.com/bakdata/kafka-error-handling) it offers various wrappers and a DLQ handling. Using it myself to grab exception while processing messages in stream processors. Only gap I‘ve seen is when you‘d like handle cases across multiple operations in a topology.